# Finding the index of a number in a list in python

Tags: python

So I'm working on an easy leetcode problem and I've run into this small error. When 2 of the same number are in a list it refuses to add them together. I made it where it would ignore it if it was the same index but that has the effect of ignoring 2 of the same numbers for some reason. Here is the code

```
def twoSum(nums, target):

    for x in nums:
        for z in nums:
            if nums.index(z) == nums.index(x):
                pass
            else:
                res = x + z
                if res == target:
                    result = [nums.index(x), nums.index(z)]
                    return result


newList = twoSum([3,2,3,7], 6)

print(newList)
```

Is there anything I'm doing wrong here that makes it pass over both 3's and return None?

Comment: To respond your question, the ```if nums.index(z) == nums.index(x)``` is comparing index of the first instance that the value is z or x. It provides the incorrect index if the list has duplication. Consider using enumerate.

Answer (score 1):

```
def twoSum(nums, target):
    for i, x in enumerate(nums):
        for j, z in enumerate(nums):
            if i == j:
                continue
            res = x + z
            if res == target:
                result = [i, j]
                return result
```

- You can use **enumerate** to access the indexes.
- You can use **continue** instead of pass, but it's just a preference.
- If you use **continue** you don't need the else since the execution is gonna jump to the next iteration when continue is hit.

Comment: true, my bad, I edited my answer

Answer (score 0):

This version eliminates the issue of having repeat index and also avoids adding a lower index to a current index (to avoid duplication). as in your code, it stops when it finds the first combination that adds to the target sum.

```
def twoSum(nums, target):

    for pos1, value in enumerate(nums):
        for pos2 in range(pos1+1, len(nums)):
            # print(pos1, pos2) <- this may help analyze the code
            res = value + nums[pos2]
            if res == target:
                result = [value, nums[pos2]]
                return result

newList = twoSum([3, 2, 3, 7], 6)

print(newList)
```